# windows phone background player share

Tags: windows-phone-7, resources, background

I'm developing a windows phone app with a background player based on the windows phone 7.1 project template(so i have 2 projects). My question is how i dynamically set the list of tracks for the background player to play? I tried static fields but didn't work and my guess is that i have to define a resource in the app.xaml but how it is done exactly? I need to share a List and an integer.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audio agent won't be able to read any resources in the `App` object (app.xaml).

As far as I can see the only way to communicate between your app and the background audio is via the `BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance` object, the `AudioTrack` (see especially the `Tag` property) and using files stored in Isolated Storage.

This is described on [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394039%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

Also check out the Background Audio player in the [MSDN code samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).